# Subtracting values & calculating percentages in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('group', ''): {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'B',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B'},
 ('category', ''): {0: 'Books',
  1: 'Candy',
  2: 'Pencil',
  3: 'Table',
  4: 'PC',
  5: 'Printer',
  6: 'Lamp',
  7: 'Books',
  8: 'Candy',
  9: 'Pencil',
  10: 'Table',
  11: 'PC',
  12: 'Printer',
  13: 'Lamp'},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'),
  'Sales_1'): {0: 9.937449997200002, 1: 30.71300000639998, 2: 58.81199999639999, 3: 25.661999978399994, 4: 3.657999996, 5: 12.0879999972, 6: 61.16600000040001, 7: 6.319439989199998, 8: 12.333119997600003, 9: 24.0544100028, 10: 24.384659998799997, 11: 1.9992000012000002, 12: 0.324, 13: 40.69122000000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'),
  'Sales_2'): {0: 21.890370397789923, 1: 28.300470581874837, 2: 53.52039700062155, 3: 52.425508769690694, 4: 6.384936971649232, 5: 6.807138946302334, 6: 52.172, 7: 5.916852561, 8: 5.810764652, 9: 12.1243325, 10: 17.88071596, 11: 0.913782413, 12: 0.869207661, 13: 20.9447844},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'last_week_sales'): {0: np.nan,
  1: np.nan,
  2: np.nan,
  3: np.nan,
  4: np.nan,
  5: np.nan,
  6: np.nan,
  7: np.nan,
  8: np.nan,
  9: np.nan,
  10: np.nan,
  11: np.nan,
  12: np.nan,
  13: np.nan},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 86.0,
  1: 66.0,
  2: 188.0,
  3: 556.0,
  4: 12.0,
  5: 4.0,
  6: 56.0,
  7: 90.0,
  8: 26.0,
  9: 49.0,
  10: 250.0,
  11: 7.0,
  12: 2.0,
  13: 44.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 4390.11,
  1: 24825.059999999998,
  2: 48592.39999999998,
  3: 60629.77,
  4: 831.22,
  5: 1545.71,
  6: 34584.99,
  7: 5641.54,
  8: 6798.75,
  9: 13290.13,
  10: 42692.68000000001,
  11: 947.65,
  12: 329.0,
  13: 29889.65},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'),
  'Sales_1'): {0: 13.690399997999998, 1: 38.723000005199985, 2: 72.4443400032, 3: 36.75802000560001, 4: 5.691999996, 5: 7.206999998399999, 6: 66.55265999039996, 7: 6.4613199911999954, 8: 12.845630001599998, 9: 26.032340003999998, 10: 30.1634600016, 11: 1.0203399996, 12: 1.4089999991999997, 13: 43.67116000320002},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'),
  'Sales_2'): {0: 22.874363860953647, 1: 29.5726042895728, 2: 55.926190956481534, 3: 54.7820864335212, 4: 6.671946105284065, 5: 7.113126469779095, 6: 54.517, 7: 6.194107518, 8: 6.083562133, 9: 12.69221484, 10: 18.71872129, 11: 0.956574175, 12: 0.910216433, 13: 21.92632044},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'last_week_sales'): {0: 4390.11,
  1: 24825.059999999998,
  2: 48592.39999999998,
  3: 60629.77,
  4: 831.22,
  5: 1545.71,
  6: 34584.99,
  7: 5641.54,
  8: 6798.75,
  9: 13290.13,
  10: 42692.68000000001,
  11: 947.65,
  12: 329.0,
  13: 29889.65},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 109.0,
  1: 48.0,
  2: 174.0,
  3: 587.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 5.0,
  6: 43.0,
  7: 62.0,
  8: 13.0,
  9: 37.0,
  10: 196.0,
  11: 8.0,
  12: 1.0,
  13: 33.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 3453.02,
  1: 17868.730000000003,
  2: 44707.82999999999,
  3: 60558.97999999999,
  4: 1261.0,
  5: 1914.6000000000001,
  6: 24146.09,
  7: 6201.489999999999,
  8: 5513.960000000001,
  9: 9645.87,
  10: 25086.785,
  11: 663.0,
  12: 448.61,
  13: 26332.7}}).set_index(['group','category'])
```

I am trying to get a column for each `date` which would be `Sales_2*1000 - total_sales` and calculating how the categories split by `total_sales` in percentage, which would be the `sum` of each weeks `total_sales` divided by each `category` sales `*100`.

What I've tried:

```
df['diff'] = df.loc[:,(slice(None),'total_sales')] - df.loc[:,(slice(None),'Sales_2')]
```

But I get

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

As this tries to place 4 columns into 1 rather than the result per each `date` column. And for the total percentages of `total_sales` per `category` and `date`:

```
df.loc[:,(slice(None),'total_sales')].groupby(level=['group','category']).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum())
```

But all of the values come to be `100` so I am not sure how I could have a column next to `total_sales` which would look like this:

```
                2021-06-28 00:00:00                           2021-07-05 00:00:00
                total_sales      %_split     difference        total_sales          %_split     difference
group   category                            
A       Books   4,390.110        9%          ...                   3,453.020         ...        ...
        Candy   24,825.060       11%         ...                   17,868.730        ...        ...
        Pencil  48,592.400       10%         ...                   44,707.830        ...        ...
        Table   60,629.770       40%         ...                   60,558.980        ...        ...
        PC      831.220          3%          ...                   1,261.000         ...        ...
        Printer 1,545.710        7%          ...                   1,914.600         ...        ...
        Lamp    34,584.990       30%         ...                   24,146.090        ...        ...
B       Books   5,641.540        ...         ...                   6,201.490         ...        ...
        Candy   6,798.750        ...         ...                   5,513.960         ...        ...
        Pencil  13,290.130       ...         ...                   9,645.870         ...        ...
        Table   42,692.680       ...         ...                   25,086.785        ...        ...
        PC      947.650          ...         ...                   663.000           ...        ...
        Printer 329.000          ...         ...                   448.610           ...        ...
        Lamp    29,889.650       ...         ...                   26,332.700        ...        ...
```

`difference` being `total_sales - sales_2*1000`, I only included the 2 columns for visibility, in reality, I need all of the columns that are present in `df` plus the 2 additional columns per each `date` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
s = df.stack(level=0)
s['diff'] = s.eval('total_sales - Sales_2 * 1000')

sales_per_group = s['total_sales'].groupby(level=[0, 2]).transform('sum')
s['split %']    = s['total_sales'] / sales_per_group * 100

s = s.stack(dropna=False).unstack([2, 3])
```

---

```
print(s)
                           2021-06-28 00:00:00                                                                              2021-07-05 00:00:00                                                                             
                           Sales_1    Sales_2 last_week_sales total_orders total_sales          diff    split %             Sales_1    Sales_2 last_week_sales total_orders total_sales          diff    split %
group category                                                                                                                                                                                                  
A     Books                9.93745  21.890370             NaN         86.0     4390.11 -17500.260398   2.502924            13.69040  22.874364         4390.11        109.0    3453.020 -19421.343861   2.243528
      Candy               30.71300  28.300471             NaN         66.0    24825.06  -3475.410582  14.153458            38.72300  29.572604        24825.06         48.0   17868.730 -11703.874290  11.609838
      Lamp                61.16600  52.172000             NaN         56.0    34584.99 -17587.010000  19.717865            66.55266  54.517000        34584.99         43.0   24146.090 -30370.910000  15.688422
      PC                   3.65800   6.384937             NaN         12.0      831.22  -5553.716972   0.473902             5.69200   6.671946          831.22         13.0    1261.000  -5410.946105   0.819309
      Pencil              58.81200  53.520397             NaN        188.0    48592.40  -4927.997001  27.703880            72.44434  55.926191        48592.40        174.0   44707.830 -11218.360956  29.047987
      Printer             12.08800   6.807139             NaN          4.0     1545.71  -5261.428946   0.881252             7.20700   7.113126         1545.71          5.0    1914.600  -5198.526470   1.243972
      Table               25.66200  52.425509             NaN        556.0    60629.77   8204.261230  34.566719            36.75802  54.782086        60629.77        587.0   60558.980   5776.893566  39.346944
B     Books                6.31944   5.916853             NaN         90.0     5641.54   -275.312561   5.664800             6.46132   6.194108         5641.54         62.0    6201.490      7.382482   8.392593
      Candy               12.33312   5.810765             NaN         26.0     6798.75    987.985348   6.826781            12.84563   6.083562         6798.75         13.0    5513.960   -569.602133   7.462146
      Lamp                40.69122  20.944784             NaN         44.0    29889.65   8944.865600  30.012883            43.67116  21.926320        29889.65         33.0   26332.700   4406.379560  35.636540
      PC                   1.99920   0.913782             NaN          7.0      947.65     33.867587   0.951557             1.02034   0.956574          947.65          8.0     663.000   -293.574175   0.897250
      Pencil              24.05441  12.124332             NaN         49.0    13290.13   1165.797500  13.344924            26.03234  12.692215        13290.13         37.0    9645.870  -3046.344840  13.053938
      Printer              0.32400   0.869208             NaN          2.0      329.00   -540.207661   0.330356             1.40900   0.910216          329.00          1.0     448.610   -461.606433   0.607112
      Table               24.38466  17.880716             NaN        250.0    42692.68  24811.964040  42.868699            30.16346  18.718721        42692.68        196.0   25086.785   6368.063710  33.950420
```

Comment: For some reason I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'object' and '<class 'int'>'` when running the `diff` line.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Check `s['diff'] = s['total_sales'] - s['Sales_2'] * 1000`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on the following idea:

- group the source DataFrame by level 0 of the column index,
- generate a "partial" DataFrame for each group, adding two new columns,
- concatenate horizontally all the partial results.

To generate the "partial" DataFrame for each group (step2), define the following function:

```
def addCols(grp):
    dff = (grp.loc[:,(slice(None),'Sales_2')] * 1000).values\
        - grp.loc[:,(slice(None),'total_sales')].values
    wrk = grp.loc[:,(slice(None), 'total_sales')]
    pct = (wrk * 100 / wrk.groupby(level=0).sum()).values
    dd = grp.columns[0][0]
    return grp.join(pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([pct, dff]), columns=pd.MultiIndex
        .from_tuples([(dd, 'Pct'), (dd, 'Diff')]), index=grp.index))
```

Then run:

```
result = pd.concat([ addCols(grp) for (_, grp) in df.groupby(axis=1, level=0) ], axis=1)
```

The result is too wide to include it here, but when you run the above code you will see the result.

If you need, change new column names as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

for your first problem when calculating the diff this should do the trick, it takes some lines of code but works for as many dates as you need. Just calculate the differences as a numpy Array and then place them in the corresponding columns.

```
tmp = 1000*df.loc[:,(slice(None),'Sales_2')].values + df.loc[:,(slice(None),'total_sales')].values

date_index = [i[0] for i in df.columns if 'total_sales' == i[1]]

for i,di in enumerate(date_index):
    df[(di,'diff')] = tmp[:,i]
    
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

Regarding your second problem with the groupby. Your code only passes one line at a time to the lambda function so it is normal to get 100% since x equals x.sum.

If you want the percentage you per group (A,B) you should not groupy by category too. This is sufficient:

```
df.loc[:,(slice(None),'total_sales')].groupby(level=['group']).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum())
```

And if you wante the percentage regardless of the group or category just do a loop.

```
for i,di in enumerate(date_index):
    df[(di,'%_split')] = 100*df[(di,'total_sales')]/df[(di,'total_sales')].sum()
    
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using your original approach:

First calculate a dataframe for the diff:

```
df_diff = pd.concat({'diff': (1000*df.loc[:,(slice(None),'Sales_2')].droplevel(axis=1, level=1)
                                  -df.loc[:,(slice(None),'total_sales')].droplevel(axis=1, level=1)
                             )
                    }, axis=1).swaplevel(axis=1)
df_diff
```

output:

```
               2021-06-28 00:00:00 2021-07-05 00:00:00
                              diff                diff
group category                                        
A     Books           17500.260398        19421.343861
      Candy            3475.410582        11703.874290
      Pencil           4927.997001        11218.360956
      Table           -8204.261230        -5776.893566
      PC               5553.716972         5410.946105
      Printer          5261.428946         5198.526470
      Lamp            17587.010000        30370.910000
B     Books             275.312561           -7.382482
      Candy            -987.985348          569.602133
      Pencil          -1165.797500         3046.344840
      Table          -24811.964040        -6368.063710
      PC                -33.867587          293.574175
      Printer           540.207661          461.606433
      Lamp            -8944.865600        -4406.379560
```

Then calculate a dataframe for the percentage:

```
df_percent = (df.loc[:,(slice(None),'total_sales')]
                .groupby('group').apply(lambda x: 100*x/x.sum())
             ).rename({'total_sales': '%sales'}, axis=1, level=1)
df_percent
```

output:

```
               2021-06-28 2021-07-05
                   %sales     %sales
group category                      
A     Books      2.502924   2.243528
      Candy     14.153458  11.609838
      Pencil    27.703880  29.047987
      Table     34.566719  39.346944
      PC         0.473902   0.819309
      Printer    0.881252   1.243972
      Lamp      19.717865  15.688422
B     Books      5.664800   8.392593
      Candy      6.826781   7.462146
      Pencil    13.344924  13.053938
      Table     42.868699  33.950420
      PC         0.951557   0.897250
      Printer    0.330356   0.607112
      Lamp      30.012883  35.636540
```

Finally, merge everything:

```
pd.concat([df, df_diff, df_percent], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
```